# Why is my ec2 instance sometimes not terminating when I use 'shutdown now'?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I am running a user-data script on startup of an ec2 machine which shuts the machine down after checking the exit status of the last executed command. I confirmed that the last executed command ran successfully, so I am not sure why the machine is not terminating. This doesn't happen every time, it seems to only happen when the user-data script finishes quickly.

Here is the end of my bash script (after executing several commands):

```
python myscript.py
ret=$?
echo $ret
if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
    shutdown now
fi
```

This produces the following output, but does not terminate the instance:

```
0
Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'init-local' at Wed, 28 Nov 2018 20:15:38 +0000. Up 11.12 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'init' at Wed, 28 Nov 2018 20:15:41 +0000. Up 14.67 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Device   Up     Address         Mask      Scope      Hw-Address
ci-info:   lo:    True   127.0.0.1     255.0.0.0      .            .
ci-info:   lo:    True       .             .          d            .
ci-info:  eth0:   True  10.90.1.222  255.255.255.0    .    0e:c9:6e:60:5d:e8
ci-info:  eth0:   True       .             .          d    0e:c9:6e:60:5d:e8
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info:  Route    Destination     Gateway       Genmask      Interface  Flags
ci-info:    0        0.0.0.0      10.90.1.1      0.0.0.0         eth0      UG
ci-info:    1       10.90.1.0      0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0      eth0      U
ci-info:    2    169.254.169.254   0.0.0.0   255.255.255.255     eth0      UH
Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:config' at Wed, 28 Nov 2018 20:15:44 +0000. Up 17.35 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:final' at Wed, 28 Nov 2018 20:15:45 +0000. Up 18.45 seconds.
Connection to 10.90.1.222 closed by remote host. 20:15:46 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 19.56 seconds
```

I am trying to determine if Cloud-init is somehow preventing the instance from terminating. Is it because the script finished while other background processes were still initializing?

Comment: First, this should be a serverfault question. Second,  please clarify whether you want to STOP or TERMINATE(delete) the instance ?

Comment: @mootmoot I want to terminate the instance.

Comment: OS `shutdown` command simply stop the instance, it does not terminate the instance. You need AWS API to terminate the instance.

Comment: Most of the time, this script does successfully terminate the instance, so I'm not sure why this would be different. Even if `shutdown` stopped the instance, the machine was still running in this particular case so I think that something else is preventing `shutdown` from running successfully.

Comment: A roadblock in server shutdown can be anything, for headless server it is much difficult to diagnose, you need monitoring tools and log export to alert unexpected delay in shutdown. I suggest you port/search your answer in Serverfault SE.